# awk - How to print two parts of one record

Tags: awk

I got fields like this one:

```
Dagmar Schlecht(ID: 1233), Taubenstr- 246, 71108 Germany, dr_schlecht@t-online-de 1233 Shopping cart #3664 - Grüne Pillen;
```

How Can I print the characters until the first ")" appears in, e.g., $1 and the characters from ~/"Shopping" and 19 chars onward ( so the part "- Grüne Pillen" is being skipped) ?

The outcome shall be written to and new field, e.g. $2:

```
Dagmar Schlecht(ID: 1233) Shopping cart #3664
```

Comment: Read [ask], your questions are getting worse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `sed` :

```
sed -r 's/(^[^,]+).*(Shopping cart[^-]+)(.*)/\1   \2/' inputfile
Dagmar Schlecht(ID: 1233)   Shopping cart #3664
```

Here, backrefrencing is used to divide the record into multiple chunks and later referred using `\N` . Each group is defined by `()`

Same regex can be used with `gawk` using `match` function which support thired argument.

```
awk '{match($0,/(^[^,]+).*(Shopping cart[^-]+)(.*)/,a);print a[1],a[2]}'
Dagmar Schlecht(ID: 1233) Shopping cart #3664
```

Comment: Well, thank you for the code and the reference. Both are far behind my understandings. In my case it does not work since I have German Umlaute in my input. At least the error message seems to tell me that. Moreover, is this a portable solition? I wrote "How Can I print the characters until the first ")" appears in, e.g., $1 " . My awk script is like this: regexfind { all sort of comands, print}. I need to divide and rebuild the record in this regexfind{} environement - sorry that I did not make this clear initially since I thought it wouldn't be necessary. Thank you PS.

Comment: Sorry! I misused the term "record" since I thought I had read that fields are also called records. But records refer to lines so to speak. Anyhow, I need to 'break' a string in a field, e.g. $1 or that ever.

Comment: @prestalearner records contain 1 or more lines, lines contain 1 or more fields.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a prettier way to do this in awk, but this does the job nicely:

```
awk -F"[ ,]" '{cartFound=0; printf "%s %s %s", $1, $2, $3; for (i=4;i<=NF;++i){if($i=="Shopping"){cartFound=1} if(cartFound==1){ printf " %s", $i} if($i ~ /^#/){cartFound=0}}}{printf "\n"}' inputFile
```

Here we:

1. Split the record by either a space or a comma: `F"[ ,]"`
2. Since we are starting a new record we set our `cartFound` variable to `0`: `cartFound=0`
3. And we print the first three fields using `printf` so it doesn't throw a line feed in: `printf "%s %s %s", $1, $2, $3;`
4. We go through the remaining fields with a for loop assigning each field ordinal to variable `i`: `for (i=4;i<=NF;++i){`
5. If the field is the value `Shopping` then we set our `cartFound` variable to `1`: `if($i=="Shopping"){cartFound=1}`
6. If `cartFound` is `1` then we again use `printf` to add the field to our output: `if(cartFound==1){ printf " %s", $i}`
7. If we hit a field that starts with a hash then set `cartFound` back to `0`: `if($i ~ /^#/){cartFound=0}`
8. Finally we `printf` out a line feed character to end the outputted record: `{printf "\n"}`.

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -En 's/^([^,]+),.+(Shopping.{11}).*/\1 \2/p' testfile

Dagmar Schlecht(ID: 1233) Shopping cart #3664
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1,$2,substr($3,1,5),$10,$11,$12}' file

Dagmar Schlecht(ID: 1233) Shopping cart #3664
```